# Specify the other side of a hasMany in ember js

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

Is there a way to specify the name of the other side of a relationship in ember js.

Like you can specify the class_name and foreign_key args to a relationship in rails.

**Edit**

Just to clarify, here are my models:

```
  App.Menu = DS.Model.extend
    menu_pages: DS.hasMany 'App.MenuPage'
    embedded_menu_pages: DS.hasMany 'App.MenuPage'

  App.MenuPage = DS.Model.extend
    menu: DS.belongsTo 'App.Menu'
    embedded_menu: DS.belongsTo 'App.Menu'
```

The problem is when i set embedded_menu on a MenuPage instance. 
Ember is then adding an item to the menu_pages array in the Menu model, rather than adding an item to the embedded_menu_pages array.

Comment: I don't think that is what I am looking for, I have updated the post with some code to better illustrate what I am trying to achieve.

Comment: I just saw it :) There is a way to declare the correct inverse relation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the tests in https://github.com/emberjs/data/blob/master/packages/ember-data/tests/integration/inverse_relationships_test.js#L45

You should be able to define the inverse part relations when they are ambiguous.
In your case something like

```
App.Menu = DS.Model.extend
  menu_pages: DS.hasMany('App.MenuPage'), inverse: 'menu'
  embedded_menu_pages: DS.hasMany 'App.MenuPage', inverse: 'embedded_menu'

App.MenuPage = DS.Model.extend
  menu: DS.belongsTo 'App.Menu', inverse: 'menu_pages'
  embedded_menu: DS.belongsTo 'App.Menu', inverse:  'embedded_menu_pages'
```

(My apologizes if the syntax does not fit with coffescript)